# TypeError: $ is not a function error in .aspx page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have added jquery.min.js file in my asp.net Master File and I am adding the same master page into my child .aspx page, but I'm getting this error

```
  `TypeError: $ is not a function
  -$(document).ready(function () {`
```

I am not able to find out why is this error coming when I have added ths jquery refrence file into the master page:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is where I am using the jquery:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">&nbsp;  

<script type="text/javascript">

 var dateFrom = null;
 var dateto = null;
 var empID = null;

 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#Button1").click(function () {   // On button click we must show the grid

         dateFrom = $("#TextBox4").val();
         dateto = $("#TextBox5").val();
         empID = $("#TextBox1").val();

         $("#UsersGrid").GridUnload();   // Unload the table before loading grid. This will clear the previously loaded UI in grid. Because in JQgrid UI is built at run time.
         gridload();                     // Call the function to load the grid
     });

 });
```

Comment: Where are you including jQuery? Is it included before using it in scripts?

Comment: You should Include jquery Lib before Your Jquery Scripts

Comment: @PaulTomkiel I am including jQuery into the master page and referring that master page into child page.

Comment: Show us your generated HTML

Comment: @PaulTomkiel I have shared the jquery code in my post where i am trying to use jquery function.Please help em where i am missing ?

Comment: `Master Page` and `Child Page` are in same `directory` ?

Comment: @AmitSoni Yes they are in same directory

Comment: ok.. try to use `CDN`

Comment: jQuery is in header or footer?

Comment: Try to use root url: `src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"`

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy i tried with this but issue is same

Comment: @ChaitanyaGadkari Its is header..

Comment: @AmitSoni I am trying to use jquery function in `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">&nbsp;  
` is it correct ?

Comment: No, Your doing it in wrong way, you need to put it in `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>`

Comment: are you sure the jquery script is loading, check for any console error for 404. also network tab. by the way why are you using so old version of jquery?

Comment: Do i need to put `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"> </asp:Content>` in child page ?

Comment: yes u need to put your script inside this

Answer (score 0):

Put your library before script tag, like this:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in master page.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
     <Scripts>                                
         <asp:ScriptReference Name="jQuery.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```